# Determine the open cover for set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

The set is given as subset $X = \{(x, y) | x > 0, y > 0\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The set is open. Find an open cover for the set that does not admit a finite subcover. The purpose is to show that the set is compact directly without referencing the Heine-Borel property.

If I find the open cover with no finite subcover, then it shows that the set is not compact by definition. I understand the idea of the question, but I'm not quite sure how to go about actually finding an open cover.

Is there a beginner process I could follow? I've basically just been guessing without any luck. What intuition goes behind this and how do I check that I have the correct open cover?

Thank you!

Comment: I think your fourth sentence is incorrect. As for an open cover without a finite subcover, little balls around each of the points of any radius you like should do it.

Comment: If a set $X\subset \mathbb R^2$ is not bounded   (like this one) then a collection of bounded open sets covering $X$ cannot have a finite subcover.  If a set $X\subset \mathbb R^2$ is not closed (like this one) then find a limit point $(x_0,y_0)$ of $X$ not in the set (quite a few choices here).  Construct your cover keeping that point in mind.  Advice for beginners and also for the rest of us.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson so, for the limit point, could I take $(x,y)=(0,0)$? Using the $(0,0)$, I need to make the cover, so would the cover $\{(1/n,1/n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ work?

Comment: or i was thinking about $B((0, 0), r)$ the ball with radius $r$?

Comment: @JohnDouma so if i take any point say $(x,y) = (1,1)$, and consider the little ball around it it with radius $r$, $B((1,1),r)$, then this would be an open cover for the set?

Comment: @eddie You need one of those for each point in the set. Just make sure that each ball is small enough so that it is fully contained in the entire set. Then, no finite collection of those will cover the entire set.

Comment: @JohnDouma i think i understand the idea of what you're saying, but I'm having a hard time applying it. Would $B((0,0),r)$ open cover work? i feel like it won't because it's for a specific point, not every point right? so i need $B((a,b),r)$ where $r=min(x,y)$ maybe? I'm sorry if I'm way off, I'm just really confused and I've been at this problem for over 2 days now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Beginners" get given problems like this often enough.  The goal is to drill the idea of open covers and compactness.

*But there is a secret: they are all the same*!  The other secret is that "beginners" do not see that they are all the same until they have drilled repetively enough so that it sinks in.  It is tempting to fuss about the set given to you and worry it to death.  *But you can use the exact same argument for every set given.*

**Idea 1.** In $\mathbb R^2$ (or any metric space) construct the expanding sequence of open balls centered at $(0,0)$ and with radius $n=1,2,3, \dots$
$$O_n= \{ (x,y): x^2 + y^2 < n\}.$$

This collection $\{O_n\}$ is an open cover of **every** set.  There is no finite subcover of **any** unbounded set.

**Idea 2.** In $\mathbb R^2$ (or any metric space) construct the contracting sequence of closed balls centered at $(0,0)$ and with radius $\frac1n$, for  $n=1,2,3, \dots$
$$C_n= \left\{ (x,y): x^2 + y^2 \leq \frac1n\right\}.$$

Take complements: $U_n =\mathbb R^2 \setminus C_n$.

This collection $\{U_n\}$ is an expanding sequence of open sets that covers  **every** set that does not contain the point $(0,0)$.   There is no finite cover of **any**  set that has $(0,0)$ as a limit point.

**Standard baby analysis problem:**  Show that this set $ E = \dots$ in $\mathbb R^n$ is not compact by constructing a cover of $E$ by a family of open sets that contains no finite subcover of $E$.

**Hint 1**:  If $E$ is unbounded copy **Idea #1**.  Pay no attention to $E$ other than to note that it is unbounded.

**Hint 2**:  If $E$, unfortunately, is bounded, then find a limit point of $E$ that is not a member of $E$. Pay no attention to $E$ other than to note that it does not contain that limit point.  Copy **Idea #2** using that limit point in place of $(0,0)$ in the idea.

This works in $\mathbb R^n$ because a set there is compact if and only if it is bounded and contains all of its limit points (i.e., is closed).  In a general metric space it may be the case that some  closed, bounded sets fail to be compact.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U_n=\{(x,y): 0\lt x\lt n\text{ and }0\lt y\lt n \}$ for $n$, a positive integer.

Then, for any $(x,y)\in X$, take $N\gt\text{ max}(x,y)$ so that $(x,y)\in U_N$. It is clear that the union of all of the $U_n$s form an open cover of $X$ and $U_1\subset U_2\subset ...$. Therefore, if there is a finite subcover, there would be a $U_M$ that covered a maximal area. But $(M+1, M+1)$ is not in $U_M$ so there can be no finite subcover.

Comment: so the ball $B_N$ is $B((x,y),r)$, where $r>max(x,y)$, for any $(x,y)$? Sorry I'm not familiar with the notation $B_N$, $B_M$, and $B_ns$, since it's different then class notation with $B(x,r)$ style. Could you please clarify this for me on how I should interpret your notation in terms of mine

Comment: @eddie I'm sorry about that. I defined $U_n$ and then used $B_n$. I changed it. The $U_n$ are open squares with their lower left corners at the origin. They are nested and cover the entire first quadrant of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: $U_N$ is the set you defined, and for any element of $X$, have that if $N>max(x,y)$, then the element of $X$ will be an element of $U_N$. So then, the union of all the different elements of $U_N$ will be nested and create the open cover for $X$. So the nesting of the $U_N$ is what defines the open cover for $X$, and there is no finite subcover since there is no $U_M$ that covers the maximal area since $(M+1.M+1)$ will not be in $U_M$. Is this correct? Could you explain why there is no finite subcover with the $U_M$? Is the $U_M$ defined the same as $U_n$? I'm confused over why there is none

Comment: If there is a finite subcover, there will be a largest square,(that's what I call $U_M$),  but that largest square won't cover all of quadrant I.